# Rails: Sunspot text searching with model associations, using :through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, sunspot

How do I search with associations and through with sunspot?

```
class StaticController < ApplicationController

  def search
    @search = Sunspot.search Business, Service do
      fulltext params[:q]
      paginate :per_page => 10
      order_by_geodist(:location, *Geocoder.coordinates(params[:loc]))
    end
      @biz = @search.results

end
```

---

```
class Business < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :services, :through => :professionals

  searchable  do
    text :name #name in business column
    # how to do I get the services?
  end

end
```

---

```
class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :service
  belongs_to :professional
end
```

---

```
class Professional < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :business
  has_many :services, as: :servicable
end
```

---

In the view, I have this (lots of looping)

```
<%= @biz.each do |b| %>
  <%= b.name %>

  <!-- looping through professionals model -->
  <% b.professionals.each do |prof| %>

    <!-- looping through services model -->
    <% prof.services.each do |s| %>
      <%= s.service %>
    <% end %>

  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This works if I search for a name that is within the business model, but what if I'm searching through a term that's in the `Service` model? It won't display correctly because my view is only coming from the business side. How do I make it so the business name will pop up if I search through `Service` model?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will need to make additional indexes for the associated models in the calling model to make this happen. For example:

```
class Business < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :name
 has_many :services, :through => :professionals

 searchable  do
  text :name #name in business column
  text :services do  # this one for full text search
     services.map(&:service).compact.join(" ")
  end
  string :services , :multiple => true do #this one for exact searches
     services.map(&:service).compact
  end
 end
end
```

After that you can do queries like:

```
Bussines.search do 
  with(:services, "some_service")
end.execute.results
```

Now you no longer have to do join on mysql tables to fetch data. You can just fetch data from the solr. This is one of biggest advantages of solr.

I hope this makes it clear. Fell free to drop a comment if you need more details.