# Search has_many:through association in sunspot in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, sunspot, sunspot-rails

I have a model Product

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :user
has_many :category_products
has_many :categories , through: :category_products
```

I want a full text search in categories and user also but it can't work

```
searchable do
text :title, :boost => 5
text :description
text :categories do 
  categories.map(&:name)
end
text :user do
  user.first_name
end
```

end

Comment: Hi @usman! Please add some details about what happens, and any error messages you're getting.

Comment: Not any error but I can't get categories and user data when enter relevant to that

Comment: check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19628513/rails-sunspot-text-searching-with-model-associations-using-through